# 'Cannot resolve symbol R' error after using library

Tags: android, bluetooth, runtime-error, shared-libraries

I use a library for bluetooth on Android Studio. This library's url is not different from others.

```
me.aflak.libraries:bluetooth:1.2.4
```

I add that library in depencies like that

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'me.aflak.libraries:bluetooth:1.2.4'}
```

I sync that lib without error but when I run that project, every R codes turning to red.

Other users of this lib hadn't got error. Where I did make mistake?

**EDIT GRADLE**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "goksu.in.kartalproje"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'me.aflak.libraries:bluetooth:1.2.4'
 }
```

Comment: It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1

Comment: what is `minSdkVersion` of your project?

Comment: I use Android Studio not Eclipse :(

Comment: This is not relevant.

Comment: Start using Android Studio.. you will enjoy

Comment: I already using android studio.